# Using trig substitution to solve for integration?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

So I used a trig sub for this problem:
$$\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{9-x^2}}dx.$$

${x=3\sin\theta}$

${dx=3\cos\theta\ d\theta}$

${\sqrt{9-x^2}= 3\cos\theta}$

I ended up with 
$$\frac19 \int \frac{ d\theta}{\sin^2\theta}$$

From there how do I solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\dfrac{d}{d\theta}\cot\theta = -\csc^2\theta$

And $d\theta$ in your integral should not be in the denominator!

Answer (score 2):

$${\int{1\over x^2\sqrt{9-x^2}}}dx$$

Your substitutions are fine:

$$x = 3\sin \theta \implies dx = 3\cos \theta \,d\theta$$

But be careful about $$\sqrt{9 - (3\sin \theta)^2}=\sqrt{9\cos^2 \theta} = 3|\cos\theta|$$

So we have $$\int \frac{3\cos \theta d\theta}{9\sin^2 \theta\cdot 3|\cos \theta|} \;=  \;\frac{1}9\int \frac{\pm d\theta}{\sin^2 \theta}\; = \;\frac 19 \int \pm \csc^2\theta \,d\theta \;\;= \;\; \pm \frac 19 \int -\frac{d}{dx}\left(\cot \theta\right)\,dx= \;\;\mp \frac 19 \cot\theta + C$$

- Let me explain the use of $\pm, \mp$. When $\pi/2 \lt \theta\lt
     3\pi/2, $ then $\cos \theta < 0$ and so $|\cos \theta| = -\cos
     \theta$.

Now you need only back-substitute by expressing $\theta$ in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is guessing: note that $(-\cot x)'=\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}$, so:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta}dx=-\cot \theta+C$$

Next $\theta=\arcsin (x/3)$,so:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta}dx=-\cot \theta+C=-\cot(\arcsin (x/3))+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, substitute $t=\frac3x$

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{9-x^2}}dx=-\frac19\int \frac t{\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt =-\frac19\sqrt{t^2-1}+C
$$